# rxjs new share opeartor seems to keep observable hot

Tags: javascript, rxjs

Suppose the following scenario

```
const test = of(4).pipe(
    tap(x => console.log("observable getting warm")),
    share({connector: () => new ReplaySubject(), resetOnComplete: false, resetOnRefCountZero: true}))


const sub = test.subscribe(r => { console.log(r) })

setTimeout(() => {
  sub.unsubscribe()
}, 2000);

setTimeout(() => {
  test.subscribe(r => console.log(r))
}, 4000);
```

I was expecting "observable getting warm" to be printed twice, since after 2 seconds we unsubscribe and thus the ref count drops to 0.

We only subscribe 4 seconds later again. By that time the ref count should be 0.

But it only prints once, i.e the observable stays hot.

Why is that the case?

I expected "observable getting warm" to be printed twice.
It is only printed once.

Answer (score 1):

`of` gets completed during the first subscription hence future subscriptions do not fire the tap since the observable is already completed. If you want this behaviour, you should consider using `resetOnComplete` which will reset the observable from the completed state and the tap will fire again.

```
import './style.css';

import { rx, of, map, ReplaySubject, interval } from 'rxjs';
import { share, tap } from 'rxjs/operators';

const test = of(1000).pipe(
  tap({
    next: (x) => console.log('observable getting warm'),
    error: () => console.log('error'),
    complete: () => console.log('complete'),
    finalize: () => console.log('finalize'),
    subscribe: () => console.log('subscribe'),
    unsubscribe: () => console.log('unsubscribe'),
  }),
  share({
    connector: () => new ReplaySubject(),
    resetOnComplete: true,
    resetOnRefCountZero: true,
  })
);

const sub = test.subscribe((r) => {
  console.log('qwer', r);
});

setTimeout(() => {
  console.log('unsubscribing - interval gets reset!');
  sub.unsubscribe();
}, 2000);

setTimeout(() => {
  test.subscribe((r) => console.log('asdf', r));
}, 4000);
```

[stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-pcjov6)

Output:

subscribe

```
preview-70b26ed60029a.js:2 observable getting warm
preview-70b26ed60029a.js:2 qwer 1000
preview-70b26ed60029a.js:2 complete
preview-70b26ed60029a.js:2 finalize
preview-70b26ed60029a.js:2 unsubscribing - interval gets reset!
preview-70b26ed60029a.js:2 subscribe
preview-70b26ed60029a.js:2 observable getting warm
preview-70b26ed60029a.js:2 asdf 1000
preview-70b26ed60029a.js:2 complete
preview-70b26ed60029a.js:2 finalize
```

Comment: If resetOnComplete resets on complete, why does resetOnRefCountZero not reset when the ref count is 0?